# apache tomcat not able to load certificate key - website down when using https

Tags: maven, tomcat, https, web-applications, certificate

I'm using certbot to add https to a webapp using tomcat9.0.75.

I've been hable to generate the certificate files, signed them, and moved to /opt/tomcat/conf.

Configured the connector in the server.xml as in this screenshot:
[server.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PijlI.png)

Added this constraint to the web.xml for the redirect to https:
[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxcm2.png)

The website works if I remove the https from the URL, the redirect from port 8091 to 8443 works, but if I add https to the link it shows as if the connection is down.

Here is the output of the catalina log:

```
15-May-2023 14:00:57.724 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.75
15-May-2023 14:00:57.737 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 4 2023 13:04:05 UTC
15-May-2023 14:00:57.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.75.0
15-May-2023 14:00:57.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
15-May-2023 14:00:57.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.15.0-1037-azure
15-May-2023 14:00:57.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
15-May-2023 14:00:57.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
15-May-2023 14:00:57.743 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1
15-May-2023 14:00:57.743 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Ubuntu
15-May-2023 14:00:57.744 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
15-May-2023 14:00:57.745 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
15-May-2023 14:00:57.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
15-May-2023 14:00:57.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
15-May-2023 14:00:57.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
15-May-2023 14:00:57.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
15-May-2023 14:00:57.783 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
15-May-2023 14:00:57.784 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
15-May-2023 14:00:57.784 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
15-May-2023 14:00:57.784 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
15-May-2023 14:00:57.784 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
15-May-2023 14:00:57.784 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
15-May-2023 14:00:57.784 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
15-May-2023 14:00:57.785 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
15-May-2023 14:00:57.785 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
15-May-2023 14:00:57.785 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
15-May-2023 14:00:57.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent An older version [1.2.23] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends a minimum version of [1.2.30]
15-May-2023 14:00:57.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.6.5].
15-May-2023 14:00:57.789 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [false].
15-May-2023 14:00:57.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
15-May-2023 14:00:57.819 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020]
15-May-2023 14:00:58.979 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8091"]
15-May-2023 14:00:59.071 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-openssl-apr-8443"] connector has been configured to support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
15-May-2023 14:00:59.072 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
15-May-2023 14:00:59.259 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers The certificate [conf/cert.pem] or its private key [conf/privkey.pem] could not be processed using a JSSE key manager and will be given directly to OpenSSL
15-May-2023 14:00:59.262 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init Error initializing SSL context
        java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key /opt/tomcat/conf/privkey.pem (error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.setCertificate(Native Method)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.addCertificate(OpenSSLContext.java:467)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init(OpenSSLContext.java:336)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.createSSLContext(AprEndpoint.java:467)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:433)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1302)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1315)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:75)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1012)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1028)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)
15-May-2023 14:00:59.265 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getKeyManagers The certificate [conf/cert.pem] or its private key [conf/privkey.pem] could not be processed using a JSSE key manager and will be given directly to OpenSSL
15-May-2023 14:00:59.265 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.logCertificate Connector [https-openssl-apr-8443], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [RSA] configured from [/home/pruebas/.keystore] using alias [tomcat] and with trust store [null]
15-May-2023 14:00:59.268 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2305] milliseconds
15-May-2023 14:00:59.491 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
15-May-2023 14:00:59.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.75]
15-May-2023 14:00:59.537 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/webapp.war]
15-May-2023 14:01:00.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/webapp.war] has finished in [793] ms
15-May-2023 14:01:00.332 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
15-May-2023 14:01:00.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [122] ms
15-May-2023 14:01:00.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
15-May-2023 14:01:00.522 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [66] ms
15-May-2023 14:01:00.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
15-May-2023 14:01:01.249 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [721] ms
15-May-2023 14:01:01.259 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
15-May-2023 14:01:01.325 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [66] ms
15-May-2023 14:01:01.334 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
15-May-2023 14:01:01.383 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [49] ms
15-May-2023 14:01:01.390 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8091"]
15-May-2023 14:01:01.465 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
15-May-2023 14:01:01.511 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [2241] milliseconds
```

The problem seems to be permission related " java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key /opt/tomcat/conf/privkey.pem (error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied)"

I don't see the tomcat9 service or catalina service running when using systemctl, but it's working fine without https. I noticed that when I generated the certificate file using certbot/letsencrypt that I couldn't sudo cd to /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain-name/  but since that I was able to copy the certificate files to /opt/tomcat/conf.

It's not clear which of these services is the tomcat9 one:[services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE5JL.png)  , so if is permission related I can't give permissions if I don't know which service is or how is running.

Checking on this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/320912/ssl-certificate-key-permission-tomcat-apr

The user group and users part it's not clear, is the tomcat user name the same as the VM user name?